# Adding an 'about' tab to an Eclipse plug-in

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

At the present stage, I am branding and deploying my plug-in. I would like to add an *About* section to the plug-in, and a *How To Use* section as well.

All the tutorials online on branding are for Eclipse RCP applications (or may be I have not researched well). Can someone please help with how to go about implementing this for a plug-in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To contribute to the *About* dialog of Eclipse, you need to provide a plug-in that is referenced from your feature as the *Brannding* plug-in.

For example:

```xml
<feature
  id="my.feature.id"
  plugin="my.branding.plugin"
  ... >
  ...
</feature>
```

The branding plug-in must provide an `about.ini` file with a

```
aboutText = This is my plug-in\n\
  Visit https://my-page.com for more info
featureImage = my-logo.png
```

This property file defines the text and image to show in the about dialog and its nested dialogs.

Finally, include the resources in the build.properties file in order for the build to include them in the resulting plug-in:

```
bin.includes = META-INF/,\
               about.ini,\
               my-logo.png
```

Note, that in order to see your contribution to the about dialog, you need to build and install the feature. When launching your plug-in from within the IDE, it will not show up.

The branding plug-in of *Extras for Eclipse* may serve as a template:

- branding plug-in: https://github.com/rherrmann/eclipse-extras/tree/master/com.codeaffine.extras.branding
- feature: https://github.com/rherrmann/eclipse-extras/tree/master/com.codeaffine.extras.ide.feature

See here for a brief tutorial: https://ekkescorner.wordpress.com/2010/06/13/brand-your-feature-and-be-part-of-about-eclipse/

A *how to use* section should be part of the [Welcome Page](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Fwelcome.htm). See here for a short tutorial: https://dzone.com/articles/short-tutorial-introwelcome

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. Really helpful.